# How come an object that implements __iter__ is not recognized as iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

Let's say you work with a wrapper object:

```
class IterOrNotIter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = open('/tmp/toto.txt')
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return self.__getattribute__(item)
        except AttributeError:
            return self.f.__getattribute__(item)
```

This object implements `__iter__`, because it passes any call to it to its member `f`, which implements it. Case in point:

```
>>> x = IterOrNotIter()
>>> x.__iter__().__next__()
'Whatever was in /tmp/toto.txt\n'
```

According to the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), IterOrNotIter should thus be iterable.

However, the Python interpreter does not recognize an `IterOrNotIter` object as actually being iterable:

```
>>> x = IterOrNotIter()
>>> for l in x:
...    print(l)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'IterOrNotIter' object is not iterable
```

Whereas this works:

```
>>> x = IterOrNotIter()
>>> for l in x.f:
...    print(l)
...
Whatever was in /tmp/toto.txt
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically because your class just doesn't have a real `__iter__` method:

```
>>> hasattr(IterOrNotIter, '__iter__')
False
```

So it doesn't qualify as iterator because the actual check for `__iter__` checks for the existence instead of assuming it's implemented. So workarounds with `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` (unfortunatly) don't work.

This is actually mentioned in the documentation for [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__):

> ### Note
>
> This method may still be bypassed when looking up special methods as the result of implicit invocation via language syntax or built-in functions. See [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup).

The latter section also explains the **why**:

> Bypassing the `__getattribute__()` machinery in this fashion provides significant scope for speed optimisations within the interpreter, at the cost of some flexibility in the handling of special methods (**the special method must be set on the class object itself in order to be consistently invoked by the interpreter**).

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Well, that's a letdown. The fact that the interpreter checks instead of just calling feels unpythonic.

Comment: @user589082 Yeah, it's a bit unpythonic but according to the documentation (I updated the answer) for **special methods** this makes Python significantly faster - at the cost of flexibility.

Comment: @MSeifert: ok but then the doc should explicitly warn that attempting to monkey-patch `__iter__` and `__next__` methods on a non-iterable object will seem to work when the methods are patched, but when we attempt to iterate using them, the patched methods will be ignored, and the object will raise an Exception and fail. Otherwise this is non-obvious, 'magical' behavior that violates the intent of the code.

Comment: @smci Python has an issue tracker. You could ask for a revision/clarification of the relevant docs there.