# How do I know which magic methods are called in python statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) lists many magic methods. But I don't think it is enough. It does not tell me what methods are called when I do `for x in c`.

To do this, I tried a simple code snippet to print each attribute reference:

```py
class Print(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print(item)
        return super().__getattribute__(item)

a = Print()
```

Sometimes it works:

```py
import pickle
pickle.dumps(a)
# print the following and then raise an error
__reduce_ex__
__reduce__
__getstate__
__class__
```

Then I know `pickle.dump` calls these magic methods.

But sometimes it does not work:

```py
for x in a:
    continue
# direct error, no print
```

Are there any way to tell what magic methods are called in a python statement?

Update:

It seems Cpython bypasses `getattribute` calls for some special methods for speedup. Check [special-method-lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) section for details.

Therefore, the answer seems to be **no**. We cannot catch each attribute reference.

Just take this example:

```py
class C:
    pass

c = C()
c.__len__ = lambda: 5
len(c)
# TypeError: object of type 'C' has no len()
```

Comment: Check out [How come an object that implements `__iter__` is not recognized as iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43935187/674039)

Comment: ^ and once you understand that, check out the hack in [Detect if a `__getattribute__` call was due to hasattr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52940910/674039).  Also note that pypy is often more well-behaved in these areas, CPython makes all kinds of nasty shortcuts.

Comment: This previous covers a technique to instrument all functions (/including Special methods/) on a particular object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372229/how-to-catch-any-method-called-on-an-object-in-python